# ajax post fade in after success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Probably a simple question, but I have been trying to get this to work for a few hours now. I tried almost everything I found about this on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work.
Maybe a pair of fresh eyes can tell me how to do this.

I want to fade in a div after calling this javascript function.

```
            function getRequest(){
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "/includes/requests.php",
                data : "mode=get_requests",
                success : function(result)  { $("#requests").html(result);
                    $('#requests').fadeIn(9000);
                }
            });

        }
```

EDIT: Thanks everyone. This

```
$('#requests').hide().fadeIn(9000);
```

did it.

Comment: What does it do instead? Is the ajax call returning successfully?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: The function is returning successfully, yes. Everything is loaded. But no fadeIn.

If I add a fadeOut() BEFORE the fadeIn, its gonna load slowly but then it would disappear.

Comment: If the element with id requests is already visible than fadeIn isn't going to do anything.

Comment: Couldn't you hide it first then fade it in?

Comment: Try `$('#requests').hide().fadeIn(9000);`

Comment: Try `$("#requests").hide().html(result).fadeIn(9000);`

Comment: @Shivam
Thats it. It worked. I don't know why, but it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Another option would be to place the new content retrieved from the ajax call inside its own div, set that div to display none, set the html of requests to that div than fadeIn the new div.  This might be more appealing if hiding requests than fading it in causes the layout to shift around in an unpleasing manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#requests').hide().fadeIn(9000);
```

You need to make the element hidden before you can show it. hence `.hide()` then `.fadeIn()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#requests').hide();
function getRequest(){
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/includes/requests.php",
        data : "mode=get_requests",
        success : function(result)  {
            $("#requests").html(result);
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        $('#requests').html('The AJAX failed!!');
    }).always(function() {
        $('#requests').fadeIn(9000);
    });
}
```

You *gain functionality* by putting the `.fadeIn()` method in the `.always()` callback because you will know whether or not the AJAX was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the element before fading it in, because it is already visible to the user, like this:

```
$('#requests').hide().fadeIn(9000);
```